# Can't pass a variable from one php file to another

Tags: php

I have a simple login page, and the idea is that if user input incorrect passowrd/login, then he or she will see error message on the same page. I have code in 3 different files - one is simple html, another has the functions, and last one runs all the logic:

```
<div id="content">
<div class="logo-container"><img src="images/logo2.png" alt=""></div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- All login logic is in login.php file -->
    <form action='/login-logic.php' method="post" class="form-1">
        <p>
            <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" 
                name="username" placeholder="What's your username?" required />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" 
                name="password" placeholder="What's your password?" required/>

            <?php 

                if($isValid === false) {
                    echo "<div id='alert-message' class='alert alert-danger'>SCRUB</div>";                        
                }

            ?>

        </p>
        <p class="submit">
            <button id="submit-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

```
// Check match of the credentials in database
function loginValidation($query) {
    global $isValid;
    $isValid = true;
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($count == 1) {

       header('Location: pages/signup.php'); /* Redirect browser */
    } else {
       $isValid = false;
       header('Location: index.php');
       /* Redirect browser */
    }   

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: where exactly is the problem now? Which variable are you trying to pass _where_?

Comment: You declare a variable just before to force browser to reload the page. So the variable is no more defined in the next request. Seems you need session, or pass your value by the URL.

Comment: What do you thank? There is no error description, there is no question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare a variable just before to force browser to reload the page. So the variable is no more defined in the next request.

Here is a possible way.

Instead of :

```
{
   $isValid = false;
   header('Location: index.php');
   /* Redirect browser */
}
```

Do :

```
{
   /* Redirect browser */
   header('Location: index.php?error');
   exit();
}
```

Then, in HTML :

```
if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
    echo "<div id='alert-message' class='alert alert-danger'>SCRUB</div>";                        
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! I am totally new to php, so I did that silly mistake. One more question : right now if I enter incorrect data I will got a message on that page. But if I press refresh button message is still there. Is there a way to refresh that 'error' if I press refresh button?

Comment: @Dmytro You're welcome :) Don't forget to close your question if an answer solves your problem. Thanks :) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235 - For your question, no, not with this method. You have to use session for that.

Comment: @Dmytro Your case is like [this case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147232/refreshing-error-pages-lead-to-error-pages-even-after-the-error-is-fixed).